# How do I use GPU with Pytorch correctly?

Tags: python, gpu

I need assistance with activating my GPU to run my Named Entity Recognition  model on a large dataset. I am relatively new to PyTorch, and I'm facing confusion.

When I check the environment using **`python3 -m torch.utils.collect_env`**, the output indicates that CUDA is not available, and the PyTorch version is **`2.1.0+cpu`**. The GPU information is provided in the nvidia-smi output, showing a GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design and driver version 451.83. However, when I run **`python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"`**, it returns **`False`**.

```
python3 -m torch.utils.collect_env
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 2.1.0+cpu
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Famille
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: Could not collect
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design
Nvidia driver version: 451.83
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Architecture=9
CurrentClockSpeed=2803
DeviceID=CPU0
Family=198
L2CacheSize=5120
L2CacheSpeed=
Manufacturer=GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed=2803
Name=11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
ProcessorType=3
Revision=

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.25.2
[pip3] torch==2.1.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.16.0
[conda] Could not collect
```

```
Thu Nov 16 15:48:02 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 451.83 Driver Version: 451.83 CUDA Version: 11.0 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 GeForce GTX 165... WDDM | 00000000:5A:00.0 Off | N/A |
| N/A 44C P8 2W / N/A | 363MiB / 4096MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: |
| GPU GI CI PID Type Process name GPU Memory |
| ID ID Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| 0 N/A N/A 16420 C+G ...ser\Application\brave.exe N/A |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
 python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"
False
```

Could you please guide me on how to properly activate my GPU in PyTorch? I'm running Windows 11 with Python 3.10.11 and have the necessary GPU and driver installed.

Comment: You have installed and CPU version of pytorch (2.1.0+cpu). First you need to uninstall the current version of pytorch and then need to install the CUDA enabled pytorch version according to your matched config: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/